# How to play music from URL- AVPlayer in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in Swift so I make an app to play music from URL, but it doesn't play.
Can someone help me?
This is my code.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var pauseImageView: UIImageView!

    var player: AVPlayer?
    var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let radioUrl = URL(string: "http://uk3.internet-radio.com:8021/listen.pls&t=.pls")
        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: radioUrl!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
        let playerLayer =  AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
        playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    }

    func playMusic() {

        if player?.rate == 0 {
            player!.play()

        }else{

            player!.pause()

        }
    }

    @IBAction func playButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
       playMusic()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to your plist file? It needs to be true so that you can load HTTP stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `&t=.pls` from your URL so it is just this:

```
let radioUrl = URL(string: "http://uk3.internet-radio.com:8021/listen.pls")
```